# Open new route and have its scroll position start from the top without forgetting the scroll position of the previous page in case I click back?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js and the application is single page.

I have 2 project descriptions on the landing page and each description has a router-link that redirects to a new page that contains the specifics of that project.

My problem is that when I scroll down on the main landing page, and then click on a router-link in order to get redirected to the page that contains the specifics of this project, the new page is already scrolled down to the bottom.

Then when I click back, I return to the landing page on the exact same spot I was before redirecting to the new route.

I want to achieve a mixture of what is currently happening - Whenever I scroll down on the landing page and click on the router-link that sends me to the page that contains the project information, I want to start from the top of the page. Then, once I've read the project description and click back, I want to be sent to the position from which I left the landing page, instead of the top.

I tried using this route guard on my `specificProject` page:

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (!to.hash) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    next();
}
```

Which does reset the scroll position to 0 when I visit the page, but when I click back, I start from position 0 on the landing page too. Any way to achieve what I've described?